# How to skip certain row in listview's getView

Tags: android, listview

My `listview` get data from `webservice` and the returned data sometimes have some `id` (but different data).

For those data that have same id, i only want to display them in `listview` **once**.

What i tried in `getView` :

```
    if(position > 0)
        prevId = getItem(position-1).getId();

    if(getItem(position).getId() == prevId)
        //skip current row
```

The problem is, how to skip the current row? (because the `id` is same like the previous one)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to filter the data before entering it to the ListView
Please add the data structure and classes the you use to get detailed help

I think you need to do something like that (T stand for a type with getId() function):

```
   List<T> removeDuplicateFromList(List<T> data){
       HashMap<String,T> filterdData = new HashMap<String,T>();
       for (T t: data){
            if (!filterdData.containKey(t.getId()){
                  filterdData.put(t.getId(),t);
            }else{
                  //Update the data at the map if needed
            } 
       }
       return filterdData.values();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think filtering the data is not possible because i need other data beside than id

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be that adding previous rows to an ArrayList , so on generating new row on getView() you can check that if the content of current row has an id which is inside of your arrayList then do nothing!

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "do nothing"? How to do it?

Comment: hope it helps ;) ,if the id of current row doesn't match on the ArrayList so add the data on ArrayList and setting your view with the data of the list, otherwise , don't add it on ArrayList and setting row data which means do nothing.

Comment: @BlazeTama : one problem is empty rows if the id exist on ArrayList , so i think you have to manipulate data , for example if the data entered before on line 1 , in line 2 you have to set data of line 3 and to preventing IndexArrayOutOfBoundException reduce your, adapter content by 1. as user2139233 mentioned best and simplest way is preventing repetitive data at begining! Good luck

Comment: i think this is not the best solution for this purpose. just try to set your specific condition and increase your position number in getView.